# trigger @keyframes animation, when you hover seperate object in CSS

Tags: css, animation

What I am trying to do is when I `:hover` the trigger container, it should trigger the `@keyframes` rings on the spans, just like how it does it when you load the page.

I have a codepen link here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/moERzj

```
.trigger img {
    width: 140px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    padding: 2px;
}

.trigger {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

.trigger > span {
    border-radius: 100% / 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    background: #333;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-animation: rings 1s;
    -moz-animation: rings 1s;
    -ms-animation: rings 1s;
    -o-animation: rings 1s;
    animation: rings 1s;
}

.trigger:hover > span {
    -webkit-animation: rings 1s;
    -moz-animation: rings 1s;
    -ms-animation: rings 1s;
    -o-animation: rings 1s;
    animation: rings 1s;
}

.trigger > img:hover > span {
  -webkit-animation: rings 1s;
    -moz-animation: rings 1s;
    -ms-animation: rings 1s;
    -o-animation: rings 1s;
    animation: rings 1s;
}

.trigger > span:nth-child(1) {
    animation-delay: 0s;
}

.trigger > span:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

.trigger > span:nth-child(3) {
    animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rings {
    0% {opacity: 0;transform: scale(1);}
    70% {opacity: 1; transform: scale(1.3);}
    100% {opacity: 0;transform: scale(1);}
}

@-moz-keyframes rings {
    0% {opacity: 0;transform: scale(1);}
    70% {opacity: 1;transform: scale(1.3);}
    100% {opacity: 0;transform: scale(1);}
}

@-ms-keyframes rings {
    0% {opacity: 0;transform: scale(1);}
    70% {opacity: 1;transform: scale(1.3);}
    100% {opacity: 0;transform: scale(1);}
}

@-o-keyframes rings {
    0% {opacity: 0;transform: scale(1);}
    70% {opacity: 1;transform: scale(1.3);}
    100% {opacity: 0;transform: scale(1);}
}

@keyframes rings {
    0% {opacity: 0;transform: scale(1);}
    70% {opacity: 1;transform: scale(1.3);}
    100% {opacity: 0;transform: scale(1);}
}
```

I just want to be able to trigger `@keyframes` rings on the spans, when I `:hover` something else, like the trigger `div` or `img`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is enough to add 'infinite' to your animation, so that it runs more than one time:
`animation: rings 1s infinite;`:

```js
"use strict";

const element = document.getElementById("trigger");

element.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e){
  element.classList.remove("animated");
  void element.offsetWidth;
  element.classList.add("animated");
}, false);
```

```css
body { background: #333;}

#trigger {
    margin: 60px auto;
    padding: 30px;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid red;
    width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
}

#trigger * {
     pointer-events: none;
}

#trigger img {
    width: 140px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    padding: 2px;
}

#trigger.animated span {
    border-radius: 100% / 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    background: #333;
    z-index: -1;
    animation: rings 1s;
}

#trigger span:nth-child(1) {
    animation-delay: 0s;
}

#trigger span:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

#trigger span:nth-child(3) {
    animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

@keyframes rings {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    70% { 
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1.3);
        }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="trigger" class="animated">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/140/140" alt="some pic">
</div>
```

Comment: What i am looking for is for the :hover to only trigger it once. Not inifinite times.

Comment: Well, that is what it does now in my example, doesn't it? Sorry, I guess I didn't understand what you are up to. What other stuff? 
You wanted the animation to run when you hover over the trigger container.

Comment: Aaah, I get it now.

Comment: Yes, i might have been a bit unclear.  I'm not used to describe these issues to other people. Usually i can find the information, but this issue is beyond me hehe.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about this, thanks for your question. I found an article about  using an animation on page load and again on :hover:
https://justmarkup.com/log/2015/01/restart-css-animation-using-css-to-trigger-a-reflow/
I tried using a second identical animation and it works. But, when leaving `.trigger`, the animation gets triggered a second time. I'm confused, I updated (and simplified for testing purposes) my code sample.

Comment: That is strange indeed. However it is very interesting to stumble upon these odd issues. So what would your take be on this?.. resort to Jquery or something?

Comment: I used vanilla javascript, following this article:
https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/
It works, but it is not a pretty solution.
Here the codepen, I tested with:
https://codepen.io/Sixl/pen/MxemYQ
I will aso update my sample here on SO.

Comment: After some time i finaly made your vanilla javascript work.. however.. i have this problem of the background being 2 colors, when i have not specified it.. it's quite weird. Have you ever come across that? - It changes when i trigger the animation too.. Can one link images in these comments?

Comment: I guess a CodePen would be best.

Comment: The issue doesn't show on codepen, for some reason :/ I even tried to make exact copies of your codepen in a .html and .ccs file and .. well.. it is very weird, i've never seen that before. I can try to upload  the files to show you.

Comment: My webhotel is a bit cringy after my previous provider was absorbed by my current.. try to go to http://www.kazie.dk/stackoverflow/index.html

It might work.. i hope it works.

Comment: You know what.. i do not see any problem being on my laptop right now. But last night, on my desktop pc i simply could not make it look right.. I will have to check when i get home. This is rather weird.

Comment: Maybe you are interested. I posted an own question, using the solution with two separate animations. There was the problem of the initial animation being executed a second time, when mouse leaves the element:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55004015/

Comment: The problem with the "two-animations-solution" was solved by user „vals“ (stackoverflow.com/questions/55004015). I reset and reapplied the initial animation, that's why it was executed a second time. His solution of applying both animations on hover is just brilliant. It didn't come to my mind. I created a sample: https://codepen.io/Sixl/pen/pYNNML?editors=1100
I think it is nicer than the JS-appproach.

Comment: That's kinda brilliant LOL. Such a simple solution. The simpler solutions are often the best ones. I think i'll try to replicate that and see which i like the better. The JS one, keeps running it course even if you leave the "trigger" before animation end tho, the example did not.

However, i uploaded this .png of the issue i had. Aparently it is a local issue, i do not see the issue on the uploaded file, but the exact same file, without changes shows like this http://www.kazie.dk/stackoverflow/img/not_running.PNG on my desktop pc. It is quite weird, the CSS is the same, should work :/

Comment: Okay i just tested, after checking the .css again. i changed to background-color on body to #000, #222, #333, #444 and #fff - and then back to #111. It seems that the issue is only on #111 - this gets stranger and stranger and i can find nothing on google, about local .html files changing their backgrounds despite only have one background-color in the .css.

Comment: Hey Kazie. Sorry, I cannot follow. What is wrong on the image you linked? Can you set up a code example and elaborate a bit what the problem is? Plus: On SO we should limit conversation and stick to the orginal question ;) Don't hesitate to ask a new one!

Comment: If you look closely, the picture has 2 backgrounds, but the CSS is the exact one you see on the animation example. 

Yea it probably is going a bit off-topic, as we already solved the original issue ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have done a tricky way which makes the run animation on hover smoothly but when you take moues out it does not end smoothly, however it full fill one thing animation on hover. One thing i noticed that `.trigger img:hover span` will perform nothing as spans are not child to image. Please check below pin:

[Animation on hover](https://codepen.io/creativesingh/pen/pYbajd)